# How to get Entity and Table from Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection

I use JDBC and I have the method like this

```
 @Override
public void deleteStudentById(int studentId, Connection connection) {

    try {
        try (PreparedStatement st = connection
                .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id=?")) {

            st.setInt(1, studentId);
            st.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new IncorrectSqlQueryException("Some errors with deleting student by ID from table students.", ex);
    }
}
```

I want to rewrite this method and make it more general that not only student can be deleted but any entity, something like that

```
@Override
public void deleteById(Entity entity, Connection connection) { };
```

My Connection calls here

```
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.connectToDatabase();
```

and here is implementation of it

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

private static final String PATH_TO_DATABASE_PROPERTIES = "db.properties";

public static Connection connectToDatabase() {
    DBProperties dbProperties = new DBProperties();

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = dbProperties.getConfigProperties(PATH_TO_DATABASE_PROPERTIES);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
}
```

In order to solve it , as I understand I need to get table Name from Connection. Is it possible and how can I do it?

I tried `connection.getSchema()` but it returned just `public`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
      String[] types = {"TABLE"};
      //Retrieving the columns in the database
      ResultSet tables = metaData.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
```

for getting list if tables. But maybe it is better to use ORM

Answer (score 0):

You could create a baseEntity class with an abstract method "getTableName" to be sure that any class in the model must implement it.

**Generic entity**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    private String createdBy;

    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

    private String updatedBy;

    private boolean deleted;

    private String deletedBy;

    private OffsetDateTime deletedAt;

    public abstract Long getId();
    
    public abstract String getTableName();

    public OffsetDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public String getDeletedBy() {
        return deletedBy;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }
}
```

**Student entity must extends baseEntity**

```
public class Student extends BaseEntity {
    private static final String TABLE = "STUDENT";

    private Long id;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return TABLE;
    }    
}
```

**How to build stmt?**

```
public static String deleteStmt = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = ?";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = ...;
    Student student = new Student(1L);
    
    deleteEntity(student, conn);        
}

public static String deleteEntity(BaseEntity entity, Connection connection) {
    String stmt = String.format(deleteStmt, entity.getTableName());
    
    
    try {
        try (PreparedStatement st = connection
                .prepareStatement(stmt)) {

            st.setInt(1, entity.getId());
            st.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new IncorrectSqlQueryException("Some errors with deleting student by ID from table students.", ex);
    }
}
```